# USB drive software encryption?

Tags: usb, encryption, truecrypt

I would like to easily encrypt/decrypt a USB key on my PC.

I used to use TrueCrypt which appears to be not secure anymore. I found an alternative named [VeryCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/), but, I would better trust a low level encryption system like PGP or [GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/).

Unfortunately, using GPG as is will not offer a transparent layer between the OS and the disk. The [GPG encrypted loopback disks] (http://patrick.uiterwijk.org/2013/02/25/gpg-encrypted-loopback-disks/) looks an interesting solution, but not really easy to deploy.

What is the simplest solution I can use to work transparently on an encrypted USB stick?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac?

Comment: Linux + Windows

Answer (score 1):

## dm-crypt / LUKS

Using cryptsetup to create a LUKS partition, or entire drive, or a container file, is an excellent way to have an encrypted "on-the-fly-encryption" device.

It should be accessible from Windows too, see his question [How can I access volumes encrypted with LUKS/dm-crypt from Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/584883/how-can-i-access-volumes-encrypted-with-luks-dm-crypt-from-windows)

---

For an excellent overview & guides on Linux Encryption see [ArchWiki - Disk Encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption).

- If you just wanted to store a few fixed files, maybe a big zip / 7z / .tar.gz / tar.xz archive, then you could just pgp/`gpg` encrypt the files.
- There's also encrypted filesystems like eCryptFS and EncFS for Linux, but I'm not 100% positive if they can be accessed from Windows - but if a virtual pc running linux can read the USB, then a linux should work there.
- TrueCrypt still *should* be secure, I haven't read anything about it being cracked or broken, just the authors won't be supporting it anymore, but it's old versions for Windows & Linux still work. "cryptsetup  supports mapping of TrueCrypt or tcplay encrypted partition using a native Linux kernel API" according to cryptsetup's man page.