# Text file with password but cross platform windows/android

Tags: windows, encryption, notepad++, passwords, android

I'm trying to encrypt a txt file, and there are several options for windows, like using 7zip or rar to password store it, or notepad++ with securepad plugin. But I want to find a solution that is viable for both windows and android.

I tried using 7zip and rar on android, but I have a problem[image]

when I edit the file and try to save it on android, I get an error saying it can't load the file on the path. This happens because I'm trying to open the txt file from within the zip file, and save it right away (which works and updates the zip file with the updated txt file on windows)

Can anyone help me to find a solution that's viable, updating the text file easily and asking for a password over a .txt file in both platforms?

Comment: Why are you using a text file and not a keepass file?

Comment: because that's a password keeper. I don't want a password keeper, but a txt file that is password protected.

Comment: KeePass stores text file attachments too, tried it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several GPG implementations for Android, they could encrypt a single text file, but then you'd still have the plaintext (deleted) copies lying around the android's file system, so you'd might as well just go with a big gun: LUKS or TrueCrypt (successor).

- [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) is a TrueCrypt successor, with [Android support](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Android%20%26%20iOS%20Support.html) using [EDS](http://sovworks.com/eds/)
- [The Guardian Project has an Android port of LUKS](https://github.com/guardianproject/luks/wiki), they consider it alpha software, but it seems to have been working ok for years, I'd just keep a backup.
- [LUKS Manager (on the Play store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager)
- There are [windows ports for LUKS](https://superuser.com/questions/584883/how-can-i-access-volumes-encrypted-with-luks-dm-crypt-from-windows/936284#936284) too, maybe old but still working.

https://alternativeto.net has a good listing of alternate programs, searchable by platform & licence, here's [a search for open source Truecrypt on Android](https://alternativeto.net/software/truecrypt/?license=opensource&platform=android).

Or like davidgo mentioned, KeePass can encrypt text file attachments too.

---

And your 7zip & rar implementations are probably just broken for editing files "in place", just extract them first & then store after editing, or find a better app. If you don't care about the plaintext copies again.